Thread lock - Spark task getting stuck with no progress
I have PySpark application that is reading data from S3 and running some spark sql queries. It's making progress and then getting stuck on a certain task in one of the stages.
I don't see any errors or Warnings in the log. The below is a sample of the log I am seeing:
24/04/12 16:37:56 INFO MapOutputTrackerWorker: Don't have map outputs for shuffle 1, fetching them
24/04/12 16:37:56 INFO MapOutputTrackerWorker: Doing the fetch; tracker endpoint = NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark://MapOutputTracker@10.239.1.176:40375)
24/04/12 16:37:56 INFO MapOutputTrackerWorker: Got the map output locations
24/04/12 16:37:56 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 53.307785 ms
24/04/12 16:37:56 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 22 (8.5 MiB) non-empty blocks including 3 (1172.4 KiB) local and 0 (0.0 B) host-local and 0 (0.0 B) push-merged-local and 19 (7.4 MiB) remote blocks
24/04/12 16:37:56 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 5 remote fetches in 2 ms
24/04/12 16:37:56 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 7.957038 ms
24/04/12 16:37:56 INFO MemoryStore: Block spark_join_relation_6_370064497 stored as values in memory (estimated size 64.5 MiB, free 264.1 GiB)
24/04/12 16:37:56 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 88 (4.7 MiB) non-empty blocks including 0 (0.0 B) local and 0 (0.0 B) host-local and 0 (0.0 B) push-merged-local and 88 (4.7 MiB) remote blocks
24/04/12 16:37:56 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 1 remote fetches in 0 ms
24/04/12 16:37:56 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 7.940237 ms
24/04/12 16:37:56 INFO MemoryStore: Block spark_join_relation_4_1731544742_370064497 stored as values in memory (estimated size 72.0 MiB, free 264.1 GiB)
24/04/12 16:37:56 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 9.024808 ms
24/04/12 16:37:56 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 10.38997 ms
24/04/12 16:37:56 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 68 (38.5 MiB) non-empty blocks including 0 (0.0 B) local and 0 (0.0 B) host-local and 0 (0.0 B) push-merged-local and 68 (38.5 MiB) remote blocks
24/04/12 16:37:56 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 4 remote fetches in 1 ms
24/04/12 16:37:56 INFO MemoryStore: Block spark_join_relation_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 236.4 MiB, free 263.8 GiB)
24/04/12 16:48:09 WARN HangingTaskDetector: Task 1127 is probably not making progress because its metrics (Map(internal.metrics.shuffle.read.localBlocksFetched -> 3, internal.metrics.shuffle.read.remoteBytesReadToDisk -> 0, internal.metrics.shuffle.write.bytesWritten -> 0, internal.metrics.output.recordsWritten -> 0, internal.metrics.shuffle.write.recordsWritten -> 0, internal.metrics.memoryBytesSpilled -> 0, internal.metrics.shuffle.read.remoteBytesRead -> 50230552, internal.metrics.diskBytesSpilled -> 0, internal.metrics.shuffle.read.localBytesRead -> 1161136, internal.metrics.shuffle.read.recordsRead -> 1800130, internal.metrics.output.bytesWritten -> 0, internal.metrics.input.bytesRead -> 0, internal.metrics.input.recordsRead -> 0, internal.metrics.shuffle.read.remoteBlocksFetched -> 176)) has not changed since Fri Apr 12 16:37:59 UTC 2024
24/04/12 16:48:09 WARN HangingTaskDetector: Doing a full thread dump to debug potential hanging tasks.
24/04/12 16:48:09 INFO privateLog: "Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 23.0 (TID 1127)" #292 RUNNABLE holding [Lock(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@803210169})]
    java.util.regex.Pattern.escape(Pattern.java:2475)
    java.util.regex.Pattern.atom(Pattern.java:2212)
    java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2144)
    java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:2010)
    java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1702)
    java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1352)
    java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
    com.databricks.sql.expressions.codegen.RuntimeUtils.regexMatches(RuntimeUtils.java:271)
    org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage6.hashAgg_doAggregateWithKeys_0$(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage6.processNext(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:761)
    scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:151)
    org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ShuffleMapTask.scala:81)
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask$$Lambda$2635/958610172.apply(Unknown Source)
    com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ShuffleMapTask.scala:81)
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask$$Lambda$2278/1476696482.apply(Unknown Source)
    com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:179)
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$5(Task.scala:142)
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task$$Lambda$1887/20743952.apply(Unknown Source)
    com.databricks.unity.UCSEphemeralState$Handle.runWith(UCSEphemeralState.scala:41)
    com.databricks.unity.HandleImpl.runWith(UCSHandle.scala:100)
    com.databricks.unity.HandleImpl.$anonfun$runWithAndClose$1(UCSHandle.scala:105)
    com.databricks.unity.HandleImpl$$Lambda$1897/1022052823.apply(Unknown Source)
    scala.util.Using$.resource(Using.scala:269)
    com.databricks.unity.HandleImpl.runWithAndClose(UCSHandle.scala:104)
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:142)
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task$$Lambda$1655/1690411242.apply(Unknown Source)
    com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:97)
    org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:904)
    org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$Lambda$1597/1971179975.apply(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1740)
    org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:907)
    org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$Lambda$1226/1798408830.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
    scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:761)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
24/04/12 16:48:09 INFO privateLog: "disk_health_monitor" #98 TIMED_WAITING
    sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2083)
    java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
    java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
24/04/12 16:48:09 INFO privateLog: "dispatcher-BlockManagerEndpoint1" #38 WAITING holding [Lock(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@251755984})]
    sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2044)
    java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop.org$apache$spark$rpc$netty$MessageLoop$$receiveLoop(MessageLoop.scala:69)
    org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop$$anon$1.run(MessageLoop.scala:41)
    java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.$anonfun$run$1(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:116)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable$$Lambda$357/1044103618.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
    scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    com.databricks.spark.util.IdentityClaim$.withClaim(IdentityClaim.scala:48)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.$anonfun$runWithCaptured$4(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:79)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper$$Lambda$360/1312019770.apply(Unknown Source)
    com.databricks.unity.UCSEphemeralState$Handle.runWith(UCSEphemeralState.scala:41)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.runWithCaptured(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:78)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.runWithCaptured$(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:64)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.runWithCaptured(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:113)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.run(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:116)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
24/04/12 16:48:09 INFO privateLog: "dispatcher-event-loop-0" #41 WAITING holding [Lock(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@223363383})]
    sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2044)
    java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop.org$apache$spark$rpc$netty$MessageLoop$$receiveLoop(MessageLoop.scala:69)
    org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop$$anon$1.run(MessageLoop.scala:41)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.$anonfun$run$1(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:116)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable$$Lambda$357/1044103618.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
    scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    com.databricks.spark.util.IdentityClaim$.withClaim(IdentityClaim.scala:48)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.$anonfun$runWithCaptured$4(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:79)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper$$Lambda$360/1312019770.apply(Unknown Source)
    com.databricks.unity.UCSEphemeralState$Handle.runWith(UCSEphemeralState.scala:41)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.runWithCaptured(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:78)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.runWithCaptured$(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:64)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.runWithCaptured(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:113)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.run(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:116)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
24/04/12 16:48:09 INFO privateLog: "dispatcher-event-loop-1" #42 WAITING holding [Lock(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@138617961})]
    sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2044)
    java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop.org$apache$spark$rpc$netty$MessageLoop$$receiveLoop(MessageLoop.scala:69)
    org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop$$anon$1.run(MessageLoop.scala:41)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.$anonfun$run$1(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:116)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable$$Lambda$357/1044103618.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
    scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    com.databricks.spark.util.IdentityClaim$.withClaim(IdentityClaim.scala:48)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.$anonfun$runWithCaptured$4(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:79)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper$$Lambda$360/1312019770.apply(Unknown Source)
    com.databricks.unity.UCSEphemeralState$Handle.runWith(UCSEphemeralState.scala:41)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.runWithCaptured(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:78)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.runWithCaptured$(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:64)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.runWithCaptured(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:113)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.run(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:116)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
24/04/12 16:48:09 INFO privateLog: "dispatcher-event-loop-10" #51 WAITING holding [Lock(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@1282128509})]
    sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2044)
    java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop.org$apache$spark$rpc$netty$MessageLoop$$receiveLoop(MessageLoop.scala:69)
    org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop$$anon$1.run(MessageLoop.scala:41)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.$anonfun$run$1(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:116)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable$$Lambda$357/1044103618.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
    scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    com.databricks.spark.util.IdentityClaim$.withClaim(IdentityClaim.scala:48)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.$anonfun$runWithCaptured$4(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:79)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper$$Lambda$360/1312019770.apply(Unknown Source)
    com.databricks.unity.UCSEphemeralState$Handle.runWith(UCSEphemeralState.scala:41)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.runWithCaptured(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:78)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.runWithCaptured$(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:64)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.runWithCaptured(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:113)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.run(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:116)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
24/04/12 16:48:09 INFO privateLog: "dispatcher-event-loop-11" #52 WAITING holding [Lock(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@1105778967})]
    sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2044)
    java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop.org$apache$spark$rpc$netty$MessageLoop$$receiveLoop(MessageLoop.scala:69)
    org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop$$anon$1.run(MessageLoop.scala:41)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.$anonfun$run$1(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:116)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable$$Lambda$357/1044103618.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
    scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    com.databricks.spark.util.IdentityClaim$.withClaim(IdentityClaim.scala:48)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.$anonfun$runWithCaptured$4(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:79)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper$$Lambda$360/1312019770.apply(Unknown Source)
    com.databricks.unity.UCSEphemeralState$Handle.runWith(UCSEphemeralState.scala:41)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.runWithCaptured(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:78)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.runWithCaptured$(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:64)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.runWithCaptured(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:113)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.run(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:116)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
24/04/12 16:48:09 INFO privateLog: "dispatcher-event-loop-12" #53 WAITING holding [Lock(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@719699252})]
    sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2044)
    java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop.org$apache$spark$rpc$netty$MessageLoop$$receiveLoop(MessageLoop.scala:69)
    org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop$$anon$1.run(MessageLoop.scala:41)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.$anonfun$run$1(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:116)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable$$Lambda$357/1044103618.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
    scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    com.databricks.spark.util.IdentityClaim$.withClaim(IdentityClaim.scala:48)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.$anonfun$runWithCaptured$4(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:79)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper$$Lambda$360/1312019770.apply(Unknown Source)
    com.databricks.unity.UCSEphemeralState$Handle.runWith(UCSEphemeralState.scala:41)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.runWithCaptured(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:78)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.runWithCaptured$(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:64)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.runWithCaptured(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:113)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.run(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:116)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
24/04/12 16:48:09 INFO privateLog: "dispatcher-event-loop-13" #54 WAITING holding [Lock(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@725579524})]
    sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2044)
    java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop.org$apache$spark$rpc$netty$MessageLoop$$receiveLoop(MessageLoop.scala:69)
    org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop$$anon$1.run(MessageLoop.scala:41)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.$anonfun$run$1(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:116)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable$$Lambda$357/1044103618.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
    scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    com.databricks.spark.util.IdentityClaim$.withClaim(IdentityClaim.scala:48)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.$anonfun$runWithCaptured$4(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:79)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper$$Lambda$360/1312019770.apply(Unknown Source)
    com.databricks.unity.UCSEphemeralState$Handle.runWith(UCSEphemeralState.scala:41)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.runWithCaptured(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:78)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.runWithCaptured$(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:64)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.runWithCaptured(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:113)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.run(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:116)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
24/04/12 16:48:09 INFO privateLog: "dispatcher-event-loop-14" #55 WAITING holding [Lock(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@974559308})]
    sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2044)
    java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop.org$apache$spark$rpc$netty$MessageLoop$$receiveLoop(MessageLoop.scala:69)
    org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop$$anon$1.run(MessageLoop.scala:41)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.$anonfun$run$1(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:116)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable$$Lambda$357/1044103618.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
    scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    com.databricks.spark.util.IdentityClaim$.withClaim(IdentityClaim.scala:48)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.$anonfun$runWithCaptured$4(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:79)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper$$Lambda$360/1312019770.apply(Unknown Source)
    com.databricks.unity.UCSEphemeralState$Handle.runWith(UCSEphemeralState.scala:41)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.runWithCaptured(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:78)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.runWithCaptured$(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:64)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.runWithCaptured(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:113)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.run(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:116)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
24/04/12 16:48:09 INFO privateLog: "dispatcher-event-loop-15" #56 WAITING holding [Lock(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@1035062904})]
    sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2044)
    java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop.org$apache$spark$rpc$netty$MessageLoop$$receiveLoop(MessageLoop.scala:69)
    org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop$$anon$1.run(MessageLoop.scala:41)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.$anonfun$run$1(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:116)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable$$Lambda$357/1044103618.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
    scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    com.databricks.spark.util.IdentityClaim$.withClaim(IdentityClaim.scala:48)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.$anonfun$runWithCaptured$4(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:79)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper$$Lambda$360/1312019770.apply(Unknown Source)
    com.databricks.unity.UCSEphemeralState$Handle.runWith(UCSEphemeralState.scala:41)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.runWithCaptured(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:78)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.runWithCaptured$(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:64)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.runWithCaptured(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:113)
    org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.run(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:116)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

The thread dump is looking like below:

it looks like there is some Thread lock on the executor task. Not sure how do I debug this. Any advise is appreciated.

What's the stack trace of thread #292?
